# Nested modules and "@variable" access

Tags: elixir

Say, I have 2 modules.

```
defmodule Mod1 do
  @var1 123
end


defmodule Mod1.Mod2 do
  def func1 do
    @var1 * 10 # how ????
  end
end
```

Is there any way to access @var1 without having to create a special function for it in Mod1?

```
defmodule Mod1 do
  @var1 123

  def var1_getter do    # only for Mod2
    @var1 123           # any other way???
  end
end
```

Comment: I advise to read more documentation and read carefully "Programming Elixir" before asking here.

Comment: @PatNowak, aaahhhhhaaaaahhhaa

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to access @var1 without having to create a special function for it in Mod1?

No, there isn't. Module attributes only exist at compile time and if you want to expose their values, you need to return it from a public function.

Also, there's nothing special about nested modules in Elixir except that the name of the parent module is a prefix of the name of its children. After compilation, they're completely separate modules that happened to be named `Mod1` and `Mod1.Mod2`.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that [`Kernel.@`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L2399) is a plain old good macro that is basically a sophisticated-check-enabled alias for [`Module.put_attribute/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#put_attribute/3).

Comment: Elixir is far away from OOP, so nested modules are not nested classes and module attributes are far from class fields.

Comment: you can define a macro `__USING__` and write  all your attributes inside the macro and load them into your module like this `use module_name`